# App is not working in the background mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audiostreamer

i'm working on an audio based app. audio is playing in the background but when the track changes it stops. and when again i open the app it resumes and plays the next track.

i'm using audio streamer in my app

all is working fine when app is in the foreground.
Please help me with this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `Required background modes` modes to the `info.plist` and add the mode `App plays audio`.

Comment: i've added already and songs are playing fine in background, the issue is when a song finish playing next track is not being played automatically. While within application the same situation is working fine

Comment: That is because the audio session is probably closed. When this happens the app is suspend those can not load the next song.

Comment: so is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes don't close the audiosession after playing the song. if you are using the AudioStream by Matt Gallagher you will have to change to way it work we the file stop playing. Sorry but can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

try to add these line in your app delegate -

```
//enable remote control event for app
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]  respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)])
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    // allows you to play in the background when app is suspended in iOS4
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Comment: in which method and what  is AVAudio session

Comment: AVAudioSession is a class in AVFoundation framework and you need to put this in your applicationDidFinishLaunching method.